# Add a row after each row on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

```
 $("table:visible").each(function() {
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(){

      var row='<tr><td>val</td></tr>';
$(row).insertAfter("#mytable tr:first");


        });

});
```

I am trying to add a row after each row on the table. What I am using right now adds a row after the first row.
For example:

My table has5rows.
After I run this js it will have 10. Any suggestions please?

Comment: I am trying to add a row after each row. so total rows will be 10 instead of 5. tr:last didn't add any rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$("table:visible").each(function () {
    $(this).find("tr").each(function () {
        var row = '<tr><td>valnew</td></tr>';
        $(row).insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjebL0be/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.after` function:

```
$("table:visible").each(function() {
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(){
        var row='<tr><td>val</td></tr>';
        $(this).after(row); // Insert row after this row
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g326b1ws/